# Python Extracting Body of an Email Message - Garbage Character String

Tags: python, email

I am trying to get the body of an email using the `email` library.

I am successfully accessing the server, account, inbox and message.

```
def connect(server, user, password):
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
    m.login(user, password)
    m.select()
    return m 

def read_email(m, emailid):
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(UID BODY[TEXT])")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)

    # extract email body

    if mail.is_multipart():
        for payload in mail.get_payload():
            print payload.get_payload()
    else:
        print mail.get_payload()

m = connect('outlook.office365.com', credentials.mailusername, 
credentials.mailpassword)
m.select('INBOX', readonly=True)
typ, emailid = m.search(None, header)
read_email(m, emailid[0])
```

My results of `.get_payload()` is

```
PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxtZXRhIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIgY29udGVudD0i
dGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04Ij4NCjwvaGVhZD4NCjxib2R5IGRpcj0iYXV0byI+DQpI
aSBNYXR0LA0KPGRpdj48YnI+DQo8L2Rpdj4NCjxkaXY+TXkgdHJhaW4gaXMgZHVlIHRvIGFycml2
```

I've searched but can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your payload is encoded using `base64`:

```sh
echo "PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxtZXRhIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIgY29udGVudD0idGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04Ij4NCjwvaGVhZD4NCjxib2R5IGRpcj0iYXV0byI+DQpIaSBNYXR0LA0KPGRpdj48YnI+DQo8L2Rpdj4NCjxkaXY+TXkgdHJhaW4gaXMgZHVlIHRvIGFycml2" | base64 --decode
```

produces:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body dir="auto">
Hi Matt,
<div><br>
</div>
<div>My train is due to arriv
```

You can use Python [base64](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) module to do the decoding programmatically. You can also use `get_payload()` with `decode=True` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload)) to decode automatically in some cases.

Example of the `base64` module:

```sh
python2 -c "import base64; print base64.b64decode('PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxtZXRhIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIgY29udGVudD0idGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04Ij4NCjwvaGVhZD4NCjxib2R5IGRpcj0iYXV0byI+DQpIaSBNYXR0LA0KPGRpdj48YnI+DQo8L2Rpdj4NCjxkaXY+TXkgdHJhaW4gaXMgZHVlIHRvIGFycml2')"
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body dir="auto">
Hi Matt,
<div><br>
</div>
<div>My train is due to arriv
```